# eclim .classpath commands :NewSrcEntry not recognized?

Tags: vim, eclim

I typed in :NewSrcEntry command on vim under project .classpath file, but there is an error said ~
E492: Not an editor command: NewSrcEntry

What's wrong with that? I totally followed the official  eclim setup instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Most often this will be the result of editing a .classpath file that resides outside of the know projects of eclim.

Will you please verify that the project is known by eclim. You can try the following command from inside any vim instance (just type vim or open gvim if you are unsure.)

`:ProjectList`

This should list the projects the eclim is currently aware of.

Be sure you note the resulting projects. Then, once you are sure of the path, open the .classpath file in vim. (enter command mode without pressing enter so the path is visible)

`:e /path/to/your/project/.classpath`

You should see the xml you expect to see in .classpath

From there you should be able to execute :NewSrcEntry

Answer (score 0):

Add `filetype plugin indent on` to the **~/.vimrc** file.